# post moment on google plus page's stream using PHP

Tags: php, google-plus, google-api-php-client

I want to post moments on stream using PHP. I searched a lot but i didn't get any working example...for posting moment  i used:

```
$moment_body = new Google_Moment();
$moment_body->setType("http://schema.org/AddAction");
$item_scope = new Google_ItemScope();
$item_scope->setUrl("https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/examples/thing");
$moment_body->setObject($item_scope);
$momentResult = $plus->moments->insert('me', 'vault', $moment_body);

# This example shows how to create moment that does not have a URL.
$moment_body = new Google_Moment();
$moment_body->setType("http://schema.org/AddAction");
$item_scope = new Google_ItemScope();
$item_scope->setId("target-id-1");
$item_scope->setType("http://schema.org/AddAction");
$item_scope->setName("The Google+ Platform");
$item_scope->setDescription("A page that describes just how awesome Google+ is!");
$item_scope->setImage("https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/snippet/examples/thing.png");
$moment_body->setObject($item_scope);
$momentResult = $plus->moments->insert('me', 'vault', $moment_body);
```

However it's not inserting moment to stream.

Comment: Moments are not the same as posting on stream.   The Google+ api doesn't allow you to post to a users stream.

Answer (score 2):

DalmTo is correct you can't post to the Google+ stream for a Page. Moments are for a feature called App Activities: https://developers.google.com/+/features/app-activities which are not very widely used (and somewhat hard to find in the UI).

There is an API for posting to Pages, but it is limited only to a handful of partners, such as Hootsuite - you may be able to use one of them though as an intermediary: https://www.google.com/+/brands/3rdpartytools.html